# When creating a new branch where does it pull from?

Tags: git

I have two branches. I want to create a new one. How do I know which branch it will pull from to start it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a lot of info here, but I assume the answer you seek is the current checked out branch.

Comment: I've +1'd this because its such a basic 'obvious' question. Once an OP starts worrying they need the answers to allay their concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just type `git branch`, it will branch off from the commit you currently have checked out. The same applies if you use `git checkout -b` to create a new branch and immediately check it out.

Alternatively, you can specify a start point. Both of the following will create a branch "bar" which starts at the current tip of "foo":

```
git branch bar foo
git checkout foo -b bar
```

Comment: In Linux, `gitk --all` might also help if you want to verify the branches visually.